# Does a Bitcoin Core wallet backup cover receiving addresses?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, backup

I have a Bitcoin Core wallet installed on my computer (from https://bitcoin.org/en/download). When I create a backup, will it also back up my receiving addresses? For example, I have give my address 123 to someone to get money. My computer crash, and I have to install the wallet again on a different computer, will the backup restore also my address(es) 123, so I don't have to give a new one?

Comment: I think this answers your question Kristian. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9828/do-i-need-to-backup-a-wallet-every-time-i-generate-a-new-address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to backup a wallet every time I generate a new address?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9828/do-i-need-to-backup-a-wallet-every-time-i-generate-a-new-address)

Comment: Thank you for looking for duplicate topics, but the question you link to asks a similar question about Armory, not Bitcoin Core.